# Google Apps Script. Setting an active sheet (focus) in another spreadsheet.

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script which deletes all but the first sheet in another spreadsheet. It works fine, but if in the other spreadsheet the focus is not in the first sheet, the other spreadsheet crashes and has to be reloaded. Not a problem, everything still works OK, but a nuisance. How can I make the first sheet have input focus before deleting all but the first sheet?

```
          var numsh = dest_ss.getNumSheets();
          for (var i = 0; i < numsh-1; i++) {
          dest_ss.deleteSheet(dest_ss.getSheets()[dest_ss.getNumSheets() - 1]);
          }
```

Comment: So you've got 2 separate spreadsheet, and you delete all but the first sheet on Spreadsheet 1 from Spreadsheet 2. But if someone is looking at some sheet who's gonna be delete on Spreadsheet 1, Spreadsheet 1 chrash and has to be reload. And you want to set the focus from the delete sheet to the first sheet to avoid those crash. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. From Spreadsheet 1 I'm deleting all but the first sheet of Speadsheet 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the first sheet the active worksheet using

```
dest_ss.setActiveSheet(dest_ss.getSheets()[0]);
```

Comment: I think that I tried this but still got the error "Unable to load file, try to load it again or send an error report." Just tried again and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should count backward and not update the index value.
Doing so you won't need to care about the active sheet.

Try like this :

```
var numsh = dest_ss.getNumSheets();
for (var i = numsh-1; i >0; i--) {
  dest_ss.deleteSheet(dest_ss.getSheets()[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it still gives the same error:- "Unable to load file, try to load it again or send an error report." If I manually select the first sheet then there is no error.

Comment: I think I'll use your code. It looks more efficient. Many thanks. I'll just have to remember to select the first sheet before running.

Comment: from my experience it is a good idea to add a small pause between each deleteSheet call to prevent freezing the browser page, I use a 400 mS sleep using  Utilities.sleep(400); maybe you can try if it solves the problem for you as well.

Comment: please have a look at this post where this specific aspect is described : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142109/how-to-use-utilities-sleep-function/11142322#11142322  btw, it uses another method to delete sheets because at the time I wrote it the method you are using didn't exist yet ;)

Comment: The 400 mS pause has solved the problem. Many thanks. I tried 200 mS but still got the error.

Comment: Glad to hear that !

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
var numsh = dest_ss.getNumSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < numsh; i++){
       if(dest_ss.getSheets()[i].getName()!= "YOUR SHEET NAME WHICH YOU DONOT WANT TO DELETE"){
          dest_ss.deleteSheet(dest_ss.getSheets()[i]);
       }
 }
```

Comment: I get an error of 'Cannot call method "getName" of undefined.' at this line:- if(dest_ss.getSheets()[i].getName()!= "Info"){

Comment: You can't put code that is harmful for the user ... what if they didn't spot the deleteSheet option?