# Creating Multiple Google Sheets PDFs throws 429 error

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, http-status-code-429

I'm stuck.  I'm hoping someone out there has figured out a way to generate a bunch of **PDF's** off of **Google Sheets**.

I run the same report for a list of companies and generate PDF snapshots of each report which are saved in Drive.  I get a *429 error* every time with the only difference being how many **PDFs** I generate before getting the error.

The number of PDFs generated is directly correlated to how long I put in the `Utilities.sleep` function but still only a fraction of the total number of reports (i.e more sleep = slightly more **PDFs** generated before error).

I've made several attempts at using exponential backoff, but my attempts have been futile.

Any insights on how to avoid the following 429 are appreciated:

`Request failed for docs.google.com/a/[redacted]/spreadsheets/d/[redacted]/… returned code 429. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response`

Here's the relevant code:

```
var foldersave = DriveApp.createFolder('New Reports').getId()
var request = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(), muteHttpExceptions: true}};

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var gid = sheet.getSheetId();

var values = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 8, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

//set up the new report
var org = sheet.getRange(5,4);
org.setValue(values[i])

//set the PDF parameters
var pdfOpts = '&size=0&fzr=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=CENTER&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
var printRange = '&c1=0' + '&r1=0' + '&c2=4' + '&r2=42'; 
var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;

//create the PDF
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, request).getBlob().setName(values[i] + ".pdf"); 
var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldersave); 
var file = dir.createFile(response);
Utilities.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: The textual error should be added to the question. Also the question should include a [mcve]. Anyway I think that error occurs because something related to some of the files that you are trying to get. See [Debugging external host communication with UrlFetchApp](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/debugging-external-host-communication-with-urlfetchapp/)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with your suggestions.  As all the files are nearly identical and the error propagates randomly after x reports, the error appears to be related to some undocumented rate limiting for x.

Answer (score 4):

I tried something similar to [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) and it worked for me.

```
 var i = 0 
 {
 i++ ;
 Utilities.sleep(i*1000);
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community Mr. Pedersen! Please check out this [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/11715606) for new users!

Answer (score 2):

[429 error](https://httpstatuses.com/429) means too many requests. The obvious solution then is to slow down on the request by creating a time delay between calls using [sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds). This has been demoed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11142322/6143482).