# Script either gives 429 error (too many requests) or takes too long. How to chain function calls?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-429

First of all, I'm not an experienced programmer and I'm very new to Google Apps Script.

I'm running a Google Apps Script and I'm stuck. What the script does: it copies a part of a sheet to a temp sheet, makes that into a PDF and sends it by mail.

I want to do this for (right now) 40 mail addresses. If I run the script it gives me a 429 (too many requests) error, after 5 to 8 addresses. This is the heavy part, I found out: `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();` If I comment it out, it works great, even copy-pasting the temp sheet and sending the emails.

To prevent this I added a sleep timer. I had to go up to 12 seconds and didn't get the error. Great. But now the script takes more than 6 min (the maximum time), so it takes too long and doesn't finish (gets about halfway).

After [reading some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes) I think the script (correct me if I'm wrong) is pretty optimal and I need to "chain function calls". But I have no idea how to go about that. I assigned this script to a button in the sheet. But I can't see how I can run 1 function and have that trigger other functions, without it considering that the same function (and thus stopping after 6 min). How do I go about this?

Here's the full code. Sorry for the Dutch text (they are just some confirmation windows and such):

```
function exportNamedRangesAsPDF() {

  var y = 1
  var sec = 40
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert('Weet je zeker dat je alle maandstaten wil versturen via mail?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(200);
  
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Maandstaten print');
    var namenSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Alle_namen');
    var namenSheetLastRow = namenSheet.getLastRow();
    var namenSheetAantalX = namenSheet.getRange("Q1").getValue()
    var startKol = 4
    var namenVerzonden = [];
    var mailOntbreekt = [];
    //Logger.log(namenSheetLastRow)
    var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName('print');
      
      if (!newSheet) {
        newSheet = ss.insertSheet('print');
      }
    newSheet.showSheet();

    var gid = newSheet.getSheetId();
    var ssID = "138zfRxR_SQ6oRJouQsMwKQZdyZYbqarUuMCfZTc8fGs";
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
        "?format=pdf&"+
        "size=7&"+
        "fzr=false&"+
        "portrait=true&"+
        "fitw=true&"+
        "gridlines=false&"+
        "printtitle=false&"+
        "sheetnames=false&"+
        "pagenum=UNDEFINED&"+
        "gid=1186495600&"+
        "top_margin=0.75&"+        
        "bottom_margin=0.75&"+         
        "left_margin=0.2&"+        
        "right_margin=0.2&"+   
        "attachment=true";
      
    var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}; 

  var i;
  for (i = 1; i < namenSheetLastRow; i++) {                     //////// START FOR LOOP
      
    if( namenSheet.getRange(i+1,16, 1, 1).getValue() == "x" ) {  /////// START IF 1
      var startRij = namenSheet.getRange(i+1,15, 1, 1).getValue()
      var voornaam = sheet.getRange(startRij+10, startKol-1, 1, 1).getValues();
      var zoeknaam = sheet.getRange(startRij+4, startKol-1, 1, 1).getValues();
           
      ui.showModalDialog(html, "Bezig met versturen...  " + y  + " van " + namenSheetAantalX);
    
      /*if (y % 5 == 0) { // Wait (sleep) every 5th time the script runs, to prevent 429 error (too many reqests) 
        ui.showModalDialog(html, "Wachten... "+ sec + " sec");
        
        Utilities.sleep(sec*1000); //  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648338/creating-multiple-google-sheets-pdfs-throws-429-error
        Logger.log("Sleep: "+ sec + " sec")
      }
      y = y+1*/

    if( namenSheet.getRange(i+1,16, 1, 1).getValue() == "x" && namenSheet.getRange(i+1,14, 1, 1).getValue() != "" ) { ////////// START IF 2
      var volleNaam = sheet.getRange(startRij+2, startKol-2, 1, 1).getValues();
      var maand = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
      var mailAdres = sheet.getRange(startRij+9, startKol-1, 1, 1).getValue();
      
      Logger.log(mailAdres + " " + volleNaam);
      namenVerzonden.push(" " + zoeknaam);
      
      sheet.getRange(startRij, startKol, 39, 16).copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1, 1, 39, 16), {contentsOnly: true}); //copy the right part of the sheet to the new sheet, content only
      sheet.getRange(startRij, startKol, 39, 16).copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1, 1, 39, 16), {formatOnly: true});//copy the right part of the sheet to the new sheet, formatting only
      
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob(); // This is the super heavy part, running it too often causes a 429 (too many requests) error
      
      //DriveApp.createFile(response); //save to drive

      var message = { //send as email  
        to: mailAdres,
        subject: "Maandstaat "+ maand,
        body: "Beste "+ voornaam + ",\n\nIn de bijlage vind je de maandstaat van maand " + maand + ".\n\nMet vriendelijke groet,\nCJ Hendriks Group",
        name: "CJ Hendriks",
        attachments: [{
          fileName: "Maandstaat - " + maand + " - " + volleNaam + ".pdf",
          content: response.getBytes(),
          mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
      }
    
    //MailApp.sendEmail(message); // This is the actual mail action

    }            ////////// END IF 2
   }           /////// END IF 1
    
    else if( namenSheet.getRange(i+1,16, 1, 1).getValue() == "x" && namenSheet.getRange(i+1,14, 1, 1).getValue() == "" ) {
      mailOntbreekt.push(" " + zoeknaam);
    }
  }             //////// END FOR LOOP

  ui.showModalDialog(html, "Maandstaten verzonden naar: " + namenVerzonden);
  Logger.log('Maandstaten verzonden naar: \n'+namenVerzonden);
  
  if( mailOntbreekt.length != 0) {
     ui.alert('Mail adres ontbreekt bij: \n'+mailOntbreekt);
  }
  
  newSheet.hideSheet(); // hide the "print" sheet
}
else {
  ui.alert('Maandstaten NIET verzonden.');
}

  Logger.log("Succesvol voltooid")
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Start by getting all of these values in a array `namenSheet.getRange(i+1,16, 1, 1).getValue()`  You need to use arrays more get all `sheet` data into array before loop and then use appropriate indexing from that array in the loop it will be much faster.

Comment: This `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();` does not need to be in the  loop remove it.  It only needs to be done once if at all.  Your code is far from optimized for speed.  If you make  recommended changes you should expect 5 to 10X improvement in speed

Comment: Thank you! I think you're right about getting these values in an array `namenSheet.getRange(i+1,16, 1, 1).getValue()` and then using indexing. I'll try to fix that.

The UrlFetchApp needs to be in the loop, however, because the data in the sheet it takes data from changes, as explained below.

Answer (score 0):

### Your script is complex in terms of efficiency

As mentioned in the comment section, you should use arrays instead of getting all the array, this is pretty infeasible for you code. What's more on the **line 80** `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();` you should make this request outside the loop, that's the reason why you are getting 429 because your script's making **namenSheetLastRow** times a request which is the same response. Keep in mind that Sheets API has its limits when it comes to non-billing accounts, *100 requests per 100 seconds per user*.

### As a workaround

Move line 80 to line 50 as the following:

```
...
var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
...
```

In doing so you will have to make this request only once and the bytes will be stored in **response**.

### Reference

[Sheets API Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 

As far as I can tell, the `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();` needs to be in the loop, because this only works for a full sheet. What I'm doing is I copy the part of the sheet I need to a new (temp) sheet. (lines 77 + 78)

And then I use the UrlFetchApp. 

Because what I do is I have 1 sheet with some data for 40ish people and I want to send them the part that's only relevant for them, nothing else. So I copy the relevant part to the new sheet and then use the UrlFetchApp. But maybe I can do this differently?

Comment: I suggested the above mentioned because **url** and **params** are defined outside the loop and `response` but as you mention you are copying in the loop, this is pretty complex for Google Apps script Limitations and Sheets API Limitations. I'd suggest you to use a Spreadsheet with a bound Script in it that contains this information (email user and payload request) and then use a Time Trigger that runs every 1 min and process X rows in order to avoid 429 error. Other than that you'll have to increase Sheets API Quota by having a billing account.