# How to wait for GAS custom function to finish and then continue using google sheets api?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using **Google Sheets api** for creating a spreadsheet with multiple sheets, all of which have **custom function**, which is written in **Google App Script**. This function fetches data from my server, and usually there are at least 25 function calls.

Now I want to download the file using google sheets api, once all the custom functions are finished properly.

How do I **wait** for all **custom functions** to **finish** and then proceed with my google sheets api calls?

Comment: Can you add some code snippet here ?

Comment: Have you tried SpreadsheetApp.flush()

Comment: @StefanvanAalst Yes I have, and it has not helped me. Sheets API execution keeps on going without waiting for custom functions.

Comment: Is this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142109/how-to-use-utilities-sleep-function

Comment: @StefanvanAalst sleep function will halt the execution of custom function, it won't halt the execution of Google Sheets API, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is still looking for an answer, I found a way that may not be ideal, but it works.

```
def check_if_ready(spreadsheet_id):
    no_of_retry = 5
    response = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,fields='sheets(data.rowData.values(effectiveValue))').execute()
    i = 1
    while 'errorValue' in str(response):
        if i > no_of_retry:
            return Response({'message': 'Error!'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        response = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,fields='sheets(data.rowData.values(effectiveValue))').execute()
        time.sleep(5)
        i += 1
```

since **errorValue** will be returned for the custom function which is not calculated properly or is still being calculated at the time of the API call.